# Getting previous page Tokens in Google Drive API v3

Tags: google-drive-api

I am attempting to write a program in Python that get a list of changes in the Google Drive API.

I've noticed success in this by using v2 of the API but not for v3 of the API.

The reason being v3 requires a page token. According the Google Drive API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/changes/getStartPageToken), this is used for acquiring a list of future changes. This means that you cannot get previous changes unless you have a prior page token.

In v2 the page token is not required and therefore I can exclude the page token in the API call and get a list of all changes (which is what I want).

Is there a way that I can get the first page token so that I can get all changes in v3? Is there another way around this?

Comment: Hi there @TailonR! I just updated my answer with additional info, give it a look and let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your main goal is to get a list of all changes inside a drive, you can do it very easily with the [`Changes.list()`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/changes/list) method. If you want to list the changes of your main drive, you only have to leave the `driveId` parameter blank.

## UPDATE

Alternatively you could use the method [`changes.getStartPageToken`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/getStartPageToken). That method returns the token that will be used for the next change. So you only need to subtract 1 to that token to know the actual page number. Then you can interact from 1 to that number to have a full list of pages.

Comment: Your update worked for me, thank you